# Javax.scripts not working well when I try to execute an operation

Tags: java

I´m trying to build a calculator but i ran into an issue by the time i press the btn_equal button
here´s the code source

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Calculadora extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine se = sem.getEngineByExtension("js");
}
```

this is where i imported the libraries

```
private void btn_equalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        try {
            System.out.println(txtOperacion.getText());

            var resultado = se.eval(txtOperacion.getText()).toString();
            System.out.println(resultado);

            txtResultado.setText(txtOperacion.getText());
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Calculadora.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

this is where i get the error, it says that it doesn´t get any value

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "this.se" is null
```

the error is not about txtOperacion because i can get the value on the console
any hand would be helpful

Comment: There does not seem to be a ScriptEngine found for `js`. For the newest java versions there no longer is a default JavaScript engine like Nashorn. Look for how to add one. Or use _java_ for scripting (java REPL).

Comment: javax.script can also list all scripting engines for all scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and I been researching info on the web and I have resolve the problem changing the jdk version, I had the JDK 16.0.1 and I replace it whit jdk 1.8.0_291, now it´s working. is a solution that maybe work for u